# Jquery Selectable set selected class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I have this table:

```
<table id="tbl" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Note</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="action"><input class="action_1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Note1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="action"><input class="action_2" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Note2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="action"><input class="action_3" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Note3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="action"><input class="action_4" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Note4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And I need select td with class "action" and set checkbox in 'on'position if it was selected. 
My js:

```
  $('.action').selectable({
            stop:function (event,ui) {
                $('input.ui-selected').each(function () {
                    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
                   $(this).prop('checked', true);
                });
            }
        });
```

Fox example, I select rows from 2 to 4, but it checked only first input, beacuse only first input has class "ui-selected". How can I set "ui-selected" to all selected inputs?

Comment: Any solutions ?